# Adding to Topic: RPi Foundation Materials

Tags: discussion, status-completed, on-off-topic

I answered [a question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42807/threading-with-gpio-and-buttons/42811#42811) that involved a very basic python issue. A user nominated it for closure, and if we look at the specific "on topic" points, he was correct. Currently, our on topic points are listed as:

- Raspberry Pi hardware, including GPIO and other related electronics.
- Raspberry Pi peripherals.
- Software specific to the Raspberry Pi.
- Operating Systems built for the Raspberry Pi.

The code the OP listed was copy and pasted from the Raspberry Pi Foundation's documentation. If the OP had asked the question on StackOverflow, and referenced the manual (as they did/should), I have no doubt it would have been migrated here in minutes. The code may not be specific to the RPi, but the source material is.

With that in mind, I voted to leave the question open, and I think we should consider officially including *Questions about materials published or provided by the Raspberry Pi Foundation* as an official topic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**YES**, answering questions about materials puplished/provided by the RPI Foundation is well within the scope of our site.

Comment: This definitely seems to be the more popular option so far. Out of curiosity, how does one change the official points?

Comment: There's an edit button on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I wasn't sure if mods did it or StackExchange. Good to know.

Answer (score -2):

**No**, leave that to the people of the Foundation - at their place.

Comment: I upvoted both these although I actually agree more with the former.  Perhaps we could have a stock answer with some email addresses noting that the foundation will certainly ignore you but you are free to keep trying ;D

Comment: @goldilocks: Can you clarify which is the former? The order of the answers is not guaranteed.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Good point.  I guess I felt it was implicit I'd upvoted the other one first and hence it would be the former but I do notice even "oblique" is too kind a word for my writing style sometimes.  Anyway that's what I meant and in any case obviously democracy has spoken here (not that that means we get to vote on anything and everything...).  I or one of the other mods (i.e., someone who didn't *lose* the last election :P) will get around to making this more explicit in the "on topics" page (if it hasn't happened already).